# Regex for detecting linear searches

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to build a regex for detecting linear search in source code (C-like syntax).

The loop declaration itself is not a big deal i.e. for, while, do etc. I can add those later.

The specific problem I'm having is detecting if statements within `{}` blocks.

So far I have this for detecting one kind of loop block.

```
BOOST_FOREACH\([^\)]*\)\W*{[^}]*}
```

How might I go about finding an `if` statement between `{[^}]*}`?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you're alright doing this in more than one operation it might be worth checking out the flip-flop operator `..` as you could use that to select the part that is between the brackets and then operate on that. The second thing to think about is I think c is a type one formal grammer so may not be very suitable to be parsed with regexes, have you thought of using a parser?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I am not really interested in rolling my own grammar or writing a compiler plug in. I just want a quick and dirty script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start:

`(BOOST_FOREACH\([^\)]*\)\W*\{[^{}]*?(if\(.*?\).*?\{.*?\})[^{}]*?\})`

The first captured group will contain the `BOOST_FOREACH` block and the second captured group will contain the `if` block.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/aB1rX8)

### Sample String

```
BOOST_FOREACH()
{
if(hello){
    //some code
}
}
```

#### Match 1

```
BOOST_FOREACH()
{
if(hello)
{
    //some code
}
}
```

#### Match 2

```
if(hello)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Turning off greedy matching with `*?` is a great idea. This will help solve my problem thank you.